# struts1 to struts2 migration message resource

Tags: struts2, migration, struts1, struts-1

Currently we are using Struts1 and we want to use struts2(convention+annotation) for incoming projects.

I'm having a problem with struts2 regarding message resource
in Struts1 we use a custom `MessageResourceFactory` which configured in `struts-config.xml`

```
<message-resource factory="" param="">
```

we used `<bean:message>` tags in struts1 to call the messages.

I can't find a good way to do it in struts2

any recommendation?

Comment: What problem are you trying to solve?

Comment: thanks for your comment

I'm wondering how to achieve the same result with struts2

our messages are in database

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Never mind I ended up, overwriting the defaultTextProvider from Struts2 , define a bean for it in struts.xml and also set it as TextProvider that should be used.

Comment: The answer no where matches the question being asked.